# Prisma ^2.0 can't handle database creation and table creation?

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, prisma

When I tried other ORM systems(Laravel's ORM), I used the ORM system to give me direct control over the database server, such as the creation and deletion of the database and the deletion of tables.

I wonder if Prisma doesn't offer that kind of function. Does Prisma offer these functions?

I looked up the official document but I couldn't find it. Is it because of SQL injection that doesn't provide this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prisma does offer this functionality via [Prisma Migrate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-migrate).

In short:

- **Prisma Client** lets you send database queries at *runtime* of your application to read and write data in your database.
- **Prisma Migrate** lets you manage your database schema (e.g. creating, modifying and deleting tables)

You can follow this guide to learn how to get started with Prisma Migrate: https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch-prisma-migrate-typescript-postgres

Comment: Thank you! best answer. [prisma migrate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-migrate), I can found your answer in it